# Yahoo messenger with proxy on kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, pidgin, yahoo-messenger, kopete

I am trying to connect to yahoo chat on kubuntu through squid proxy. The proxy system is username/password based. I have tried different solutions like pidgin (has a proxy bug http://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/496), kopete (i could not find proxy settings here at all) and gyachi (this looked promising, has a proxy option but does not allow to add username/password).

I have also tried using yahoo messenger using wine but that didnt work out since it is trying to get the proxy from IE.

I have run out of ideas now :). Has someone here tried the same thing? Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This squid-cache wiki entry might help : 
[Securing Instant Messengers - Yahoo! Messenger](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Chat#ConfigExamples.2BAC8-Chat.2BAC8-YahooMessenger.Yahoo.21_Messenger)

> Squid Configuration File to Include:
>
> ```
> # Yahoo! Messenger
> acl ym dstdomain .messenger.yahoo.com .psq.yahoo.com
> acl ym dstdomain .us.il.yimg.com .msg.yahoo.com .pager.yahoo.com
> acl ym dstdomain .rareedge.com .ytunnelpro.com .chat.yahoo.com
> acl ym dstdomain .voice.yahoo.com
>
> acl ymregex url_regex yupdater.yim ymsgr myspaceim
>
> # Other protocols Yahoo!Messenger uses ??
> acl ym dstdomain .skype.com .imvu.com
>
> http_access deny ym
> http_access deny ymregex
> ```

The above script example disallows access. So use rather `http_access allow`.

This is also demonstrated in [Can we use squid proxy for Yahoo Messenger](http://www.squid-cache.org/mail-archive/squid-users/200405/0861.html).

Comment: sorry, but i dont have access on the squid proxy configuration. anything which i can do on the messenger side? or is this because of the proxy blocking the port? if thats the case, then how does yahoo messenger work in windows?

Comment: You mean Yahoo! Messenger works in Windows that is connecting to the same squid proxy ?